# Blackberry Signature Tool - Unable to Sign behind Proxy

Tags: blackberry, windows-7, java-me, proxy

I have the following dilemma. I was able to register my signing keys after many failure and attempt. But now to sign the application the signature tool gives the following error:

Status:"Failed-See Details"
Details:" General failure.  Please try again. Server may be unavailable"

I am connecting through a proxy server but the signature tool is not prompting for my username and password.

I have upgraded to Windows 7 Professional 64bits - This is when the problem started.

Comment: Check these links: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Unable-to-register-keys-or-sign-a-file-while-behind-a-proxy/ta-p/445842 http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Signature-Tool-fails-to-launch-after-configuring-a-proxy-server/ta-p/445816

Comment: I had tried the above before but it did not work. I think the problem as to do with my computer. If i was to ping any website it always fails on first attempt. Remote desktop does not connect on first attempt too.

Comment: http://isthesigningserverdown.com/chart/index.php?sigType=RRT This link gives you up to date details about when the server was low